# Why is the variable holding the input value always logged as empty?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

When I `console.log` the variable that holds the input value, it logs an empty string. The same thing happens with `alert`. You can test the code in the console and you will see that the output is really there, but empty.

```js
(function() {
  var button = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
  var userInput = document.getElementById("user_input").value;

  button[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log(userInput);
  }, false);
})();
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="user_input" type="text" placeholder="add new task">
  <button type="button">Add</button>
</form>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: It's not invisible. It's empty, meaning the input's value attribute is empty.

Comment: You are getting an empty value. Try: `console.log('the value is: ' + userInput);` so you can see the statement in the console, but you would need to add your HTML to the question so people here can help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were getting the value when the document is loaded. At this time, the value is empty. You need to get the value inside your click event.

```js
(function() {
  var button = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
  var userInput = document.getElementById("user_input"); // Get only the element.

  button[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log(userInput.value); // Get the value here.
  }, false);
})();
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="user_input" type="text" placeholder="add new task">
  <button type="button">Add</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Repositioning** (Defining/moving) the **var user_input**  inside the **eventListener** also works!

```js
(function() {
  var button = document.getElementsByTagName("button");

button[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
var userInput = document.getElementById("user_input").value; // Get the element and the value all together 
    console.log(userInput); // Log only the Variable
  }, false);
})();
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="user_input" type="text" placeholder="add new task">
  <button type="button">Add</button>
</form>
```