# Input box value is showing blank on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am trying to pop out **input** box value but it is showing a blank value. why?
Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rhulkashyap/uwfzv03j/).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var name = $("#name").val();
  $('#showName').click(function() {
    alert(name);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="First Name">
   
<button type="button" id="showName">Show name</button>
```

Comment: var name = $("#name").val(); move this inside on click function.

Comment: Move your variable inside click function.

Comment: When your source starts, at the initialization of your page, the `var name` is set to value of the input field. At initialization this is `null` or `undefined`. The var is not set to actual value when you click on the button. So set the `var name` inside your click handler. Or use a `onChange` handler for the input field to set the name variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [console.log doesn't console out input value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43611158/console-log-doesnt-console-out-input-value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you initialize `var name` in `document.ready()`, the `name` variable give a value of input at load of page, so value of name equals to nothing (empty string). so you must change your code that your input value read when button is clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showName').click(function() {
        var name = $("#name").val();
        alert(name);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the `var name = $("#name").val();` inside your `click` function.

```
$('#showName').click(function() {
  var name = $("#name").val();
  alert(name);
});
```

Example below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#showName').click(function() {
    var name = $("#name").val();
    alert(name);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="First Name">
<br>
<button type="button" id="showName">Show name</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 
  $('#showName').click(function() {
    alert($("input").val());
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="First Name">
   
<button type="button" id="showName">Show name</button>
```