# JavaScript: guess is always false

Tags: javascript, html

The error is that no matter what number I input in the prompt, the answer always comes up wrong, even if it is the correct number.

```js
var numToBeGuessed = 68;
i = 0;
GuessedNum = document.getElementById('GNum').value;



function myFunction() {
  if (GuessedNum == numToBeGuessed) {

    alert("Correct Guess! The number is in fact " + numToBeGuessed)
  } else {
    io = i + 1;

    alert("Wrong Guess!");
    alert("Number of Guesses: " + io);
  }
  i++
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="GNum">
<input type="button" id="myFunction()" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit">
```

Comment: You need to get the value from the input when the user clicks the button. Currently you're getting it when your page initially loads, so it will be an empty string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [console.log doesn't console out input value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43611158/console-log-doesnt-console-out-input-value)

Comment: Using console.log() to see what the variables were at each stage would have shown the GuessedNum is an empty string as @NickParsons has already said. The console is your friend :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `GuessedNum` had to be calculated inside your function.

```js
var numToBeGuessed = 68;
let i = 0;


function myFunction(){
  GuessedNum=document.getElementById('GNum').value;
  if (GuessedNum == numToBeGuessed)   {

    alert("Correct Guess! The number is in fact "+ numToBeGuessed)
  }
  else {
    io=i+1;

    alert("Wrong Guess!");
    alert("Number of Guesses: "+ io);
  }
  i++
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="GNum">
<input type="button" id="myFunction()" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit">
```