# if statements arent working and i dont know why

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

here is the current version I'm using for a page

```
input = toString(document.getElementById("pass").value);

function check() {
  if (input == "test") {
    location.replace("https://google.com");
    console.log("correct");
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("pass").value = "";
    alert("Incorrect Password");
    console.log("incorrect");
  }
}
```

I tried it without the `toString()` function and it still doesn't work.

also here is the html linked to it:

```
<div class="main">
       <input class="password" id="pass" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Class">
       <button class="password" onclick="check()">Join</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the variable holding the input value always logged as empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43611158/why-is-the-variable-holding-the-input-value-always-logged-as-empty)

Comment: You should use === instead of == in your if statement. It ensures a strict match for your password.

Answer (score 3):

By default the input value is string, you do not need to convert them. You should take the value of the input inside the function. I will also suggest you to avoid inline event handler:

```js
document.querySelector('button.password').addEventListener('click', check);

function check() {
  var input = document.getElementById("pass").value;
  if (input == "test") {
    location.replace("https://google.com");
    console.log("correct");
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("pass").value = "";
    alert("Incorrect Password");
    console.log("incorrect");
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
       <input class="password" id="pass" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Class">
       <button class="password">Join</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are fetching the value of the textbox at the start of your program. `document.getElementById("pass").value` this code runs at the very beginning and evaluates to `""`.

**To solve this:**

- Replace `input = toString(document.getElementById("pass").value);` with `input = document.getElementById("pass")`.
- And when comparing the value, do this `if (input.value == "test")` (instead of `if (input == "test")`).

Comment: Actually, it ends up calling `window.toString` which returns `"[object Undefined]"`. Aside from that, this answer is correct.

Comment: @Theraot I am not using the `toString` method in this `input = document.getElementById("pass")`.

Comment: You claimed `input = toString(document.getElementById("pass").value);` returns `""`, it does not. It returns `"[object Undefined]"` because it ends up calling `window.toString`.

Comment: Actually I meant `document.getElementById("pass").value` evaluates to `""`. Sorry for my poor explanation.
Thank you @Theraot for pointing it out.